# Proving $A = f^{-1}(f(A))$, given an injective function $f : X \to Y$ with $A \subset X$

Tags: functions, proof-verification

> Let $f : X \to Y$ be a one-to-one function with $A \subset X$. Show that $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$.

My try:

If $x \in A$, then $f(x)\in f(A)$. By definition, $f^{-1}(f(A))=\{x\in A : f(x) \in f(A)\}$. Thus, $x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$, and so $A \subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$.

Now suppose $x \in f^{-1}(f(A))$. Then $f(x) \in f(A)$. Denote $y:=f(x)$, so that $y \in f(A)$. Because $y$ belongs to $f(A)$, there exists an $a \in A$ such that $y=f(a)$, or $f(x)=f(a)$. As $f$ is injective as given, we have $x=a \in A$. Thus, $f^{-1}(f(A)) \subseteq A$.

---

The forward containment was fine; my professor gave me full marks. However, I was stuck on proving the reverse containment, so my professor gave me a hint. I would like to know if my proof was okay, in particular, the proof of the reverse containment.

Comment: "Then for every $y$". No. This is where your proof went astray. You had just said that $y$ was some concrete object depending on $x$, and now suddenly it is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Andres's comment. A quick way to fix your proof is to replace "Then for every $y$..." with "Because $y$ belongs to $f(A)$..." The rest of your proof is good.

Comment: Can I say this following as well? $$\text{Let $y=f(x)$, so $y \in f(A)$. Then there exists an $a \in A$ such that $y=f(a)$, or $f(x)=f(a)$.}$$  If I said "Because $y$ belongs to $f(A)$", right after saying "so $y \in f(A)$" in my proof, I feel like I would sound redundant.

Comment: @legâteauaufromage Yes, that's fine.